# Convert .py file and image to standalone executable

Tags: python, image, exe, pyinstaller

I have python program with an image that goes alongside it. The image is displayed in the tkinter window the program creates and is necessary. I would like to combine the .py file and .gif file into one executable using pyinstaller.

I know that to create a standalone .py file you need to use `--onefile` but I do not know how to do this with an image involved. I am relatively sure that you have to edit the .spec file but I do not know how to go about doing this.

I do not care about the icon of the program, just the image in the tkinter window.

Please provide step-by-step instructions since I am a beginner.

Comment: You could maybe base64-encode the image and store it as a string in your program so you don't need an additional image file.

Comment: How would one do this?

Comment: I just added some code to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could maybe base64-encode your GIF file and store it as a string in your Python script - then you don't need to carry the extra GIF file around.

So, say your image is in a file called `image.gif`, you could do the following in Terminal:

```
base64 -i image.gif -o image.b64
```

Then copy the (text) contents of file `image.b64` and store in a Python variable:

```
photo = """R0lGODlh4gLxAPcAAAQEBAoGBgo...L+SwTBVhBCtCVf6lAE"""
```

Then load the image with:

```
photo = PhotoImage(data=photo)
```

Comment: do I put `base64 -i image.gif -o image.b64` into my code or run it in cmd?

Comment: Just run that command in your Terminal, once, to get the string that you will store in your Python variable.

Comment: Worked, ended up using an online image to base64 converter. thanks.

Comment: Also, how would I utilize this when using `pygame.image.load`? I tried `Img = pygame.image.load(data=photo)` But that returns this error: `TypeError: load_extended() takes no keyword arguments`

Comment: I haven't done that myself with `pygame` but it looks eminently possible using this https://www.programcreek.com/2013/09/convert-image-to-string-in-python/

Answer (score 1):

After much experimenting, I have got an example working. This is a small sample script that loads an image and displays it - the only tricky part is where it decides whether it is running from within a bundle or live.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
from PIL import Image                                                                       
import sys, os

filename = "image.png"

# Work out where the image file is
if getattr( sys, 'frozen', False ) :
   # running in a bundle
   path = os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, filename)
else :
   # running live
   path = filename

im = Image.open(path)                                                                
im.show()
```

I then build it into a single file with **PyInstaller** like this:

```
pyinstaller --add-data "image.png:." --onefile test.py
```

That creates a directory called `dist` and in there, you will find a single file called `test` that can be run on other machines with the same OS but without Python installed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to "attach" the image to your program. You can do this like so:

> --add-data "The file you want to add."

But, on your code, when referring to the image file, you need to do this:

```
image_file = sys._MEIPASS + "\file.gif"
```

Why? Because the file is inside the program now, and the directory used to indicate that the file is inside the program is: sys._MEIPASS.

Comment: I cant get it to work, I did this: pyinstaller --onefile --add-data "C:\Users\Mihkel\Desktop\Python Programs\pepe\pepepic.gif"pepec.py -w